# Azure EventGrid Trigger - Webhooks

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid, azure-webhooks

I am trying to create an azure event grid function with a webhook endpoint. But when I try to create my event grid subscription it says:

> "Deploying Event Subscription: event-store-in-delta Deployment has
> failed with the following error: {"code":"Url
> validation","message":"Webhook validation handshake failed for
> https://1e8f90c31be0.ngrok.io/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid. Http POST
> request failed with response code Unknown. For troublehooting, visit
> https://aka.ms/esvalidation. Activity
> id:1d113deb-63d2-467a-b21d-36e289fa5b99, timestamp: 6/10/2021 1:01:46
> PM (UTC)."}

Has anybody come across this error ?

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP Trigger function needs to implement some validation logic to act as Event Grid endpoint. The Azure documentation provides several pages regarding the issue.

- [Endpoint validation with Event Grid events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/webhook-event-delivery#endpoint-validation-with-event-grid-events)

  > If you're using any other type of endpoint, such as an HTTP trigger
  > based Azure function, your endpoint code needs to participate in a
  > validation handshake with Event Grid. Event Grid supports two ways of
  > validating the subscription.
- [Receive events to an HTTP endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/receive-events)

In addition you need to ensure, that your endpoint is accessable by Event Grid. Usually, the *Function Key* needs to be provided as query parameter `code` in the webhook URL.